# Mysql query: selecting from two rows in the same field

Tags: mysql, select, row, field

I have the following mysql table:

Products

```
ID -- NAME -- INSTOCK -- REFERER -- DISCOUNT 
1 -- pen -- 1 -- google.com -- 50 
2 -- mouse -- 0 -- google.ca -- 30
3 -- keyboard -- 1 -- google.ca -- 30
4 -- screen -- 1 -- yahoo.com -- 50
5 -- mother board -- 1 -- yahoo.ca -- 30
6 -- printer -- 1 -- google.com --30
```

What I'm trying to get is all the rows that have:

INSTOCK equals 1 and the REFERER  equals google.com and google.ca

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just to make sure you want to select products that are in stock and the referrer is either google.com or google.ca? For your example you want 1, 2, 3 and 6 returned?

Comment: That seems to be quite impossible. What ID's would you expect to get back from this query?

Comment: We probably means google.com **or** google.ca...

Comment: The IDs should be 1, 3 and 6. Number 2 has instock= 0. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty basic SQL:

```
SELECT ID, NAME
FROM Products
WHERE INSTOCK = 1 AND (REFERER = 'google.com' OR REFERER = 'google.ca');
```

Further reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

I bet you mean OR, not AND in your question:

Your looking for IN:

```
SELECT * FROm table WHERE INSTOCK = 1 AND REFERER IN ('google.com', 'google.ca')
```

Or you could use OR:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE INSTOCK = 1 AND (REFERER = 'google.com' OR REFERER = 'google.ca')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the WHERE statement combined with AND conditions in your query:

`// Example

SELECT ID, NAME FROM table WHERE INSTOCK = 1 AND (REFERER = 'google.com' OR REFERER = 'google.ca');`

Comment: thanks Artusamak but with your query I get 0 results, and that's not true :(

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @user523129 Read your question again. That's what you asked for ;-)